# Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency() flutter file listing

Tags: flutter

I have the below code

```
  Stream<File> searchAudioFiles(Directory dir) {
    return Glob("**.mp3")
        .list(root: dir.path)
        .where((entity) => entity is File)
        .cast<File>();
  }
```

That I expect it to return the mp3 files. However, it is returning nothing apart from the below logs. I literally don't know what these logs are telling me.

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(23190): Init 85a779e [ExoPlayerLib/2.17.1] [TECNO-KD7, TECNO KD7, TECNO MOBILE LIMITED, 29]
W/ons.luja(23190): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
```

Comment: I got the same error on video_player.  How did you fix it?